# Extract type of object to use as generic <T>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, json.net

I have a class `VResult<T>` that can be instantiated with

```
bool value = true;    
VResult<bool> vr =  new VResult<bool>(value);
```

If I don't know the type of `value`, I'd like to do something like

```
VResult<typeof value> = new VResult<typeof value>(value);
```

Is that possible?

The ultimate goal is to serialize/deserialize `VResult<T>`:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new VResult<bool>(true));
```

where  could be an object or basic datatype such as `int` or `bool`.

I'm using a data transfer object that adds

```
ValueTypeName = Value.GetType().Name;
```

and

```
ValueTypeNamespace = Value.GetType().Namespace;
```

properties so that on the receiving side I can use

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
string vt = (string)obj["ValueTypeName"];
string vtn = (string)obj["ValueTypeNamespace"];
Type type = Type.GetType($"{vtn}.{vt}");
var value = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
value = obj["Value"];
VResult<typeof value> vr = new VResult<typeof value> (value); //not correct
```

to get all the `Type` information about `value`, but I just don't figure out how to get the generic `<T>` from `value` to pass it in the `VResult<T>` constructor;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the generic instance like this:

```
object value = 1; //I don't know the runtime type of this
var genericType = typeof(VResult<>).MakeGenericType(value.GetType());
var genericInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, 
                                               new object[] { value });
```

And now you have a instance of `VResult<int>` with a `value` of `1`. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I was looking for. Works great!